# I can't export/import database from PhpMyAdmin properly

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export

I have exported my database and when I want to import the same database it dives me the following error message : #1046 - No database selected . When I  open the export file with notepad++ I see that there is no line "CREATE DATABASE database_name" or "USE DATABASE database_name"  so I type it. When I try to import the edited exported file again it gives me the following error message:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USE messagesDB

Here is my export file code:

http://pastebin.com/PPndRAv4

Comment: The correct syntax is `USE database_name;`, not `USE DATABASE database_name;`. And don't forget the semicolons. I believe PhpMyAdmin's export function gives you the option of including a `CREATE DATABASE` line at the top of the SQL file. Perhaps you could use that next time.

Comment: It still gives me the same error message.

Comment: Well I don't know what you're doing wrong. It would probably be easier if you selected a database in PhpMyAdmin before you tried to import it. Then you wouldn't have to edit anything.

Comment: Yeah . That was the problem thank you.